# Not able to login after suspend/sleep in Linux Mint 20.04 from XFCE DE

Tags: login, xfce, suspend, sleep

I think this is due to Deepin Desktop Environment, which I install just now, from ubuntudde-ppa.
I tried this post:- https://askubuntu.com/questions/818919/xubuntu-16-04-how-do-i-make-it-lock-screen-automatically-after-timeout
But, xfce-power-manager was not working?.
Whenever I sleep/suspend the system, the is no login screen after resuming, just black blank screen, with some screen brightness, I also can't reach tty and I have to force shutdown, to reboot.

Comment: Can you press e.g. Ctrl + Alt + F3 after resuming and check if you see a login prompt?

Comment: Apparently, I don't get the login prompt nor can I reach the tty, from a logined session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `xfce4` package had some how got deleted.
After reinstalling it everything is fine now